# AngularJS: Get selected item in the listbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I am newbie to angularjs.

I have 2 listboxes of allowed and denied items respectively.

User can select any number of items from any listbox1 and transfer to listbox2 with the help of two buttons.

I want to get the selected item from listbox1 and transfer to listbox2.
How can we get selected item of listbox1?

Please find the code sample below:

**MVC page**

```
@Html.ListBox("lstboxDeny", new SelectList(Model.DenyList, "value", "text"), new { ng_model="modelDenyList"})

@Html.ListBox("lstboxAllow", new SelectList(Model.AllowList, "value", "text"), new { ng_model = "modelAllowList" })
```

**Javascript file**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('myAppController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

 $scope.loadedAllowList.push(modelAllowList);
 $scope.loadedDenyList.push(modelDenyList);

 $scope.btnAllow_Click = function () {
        $scope.loadedAllowList.push($scope.????SELECTED-ITEM?????);
        /* splice logic */
    }   

 $scope.btnDeny_Click = function () {
        $scope.loadedDenyList.push($scope.????SELECTED-ITEM?????);
        /* splice logic */
    }

} ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use Html Select tag with angular [ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) directive instead of MVC helpers.

```
<select ng-options="ai.text for al in loadedAllowList" ng-model="selectedAllowedItem"></select>

<select ng-options="di.text for dl in loadedDenyList" ng-model="selectedDenyItem"></select>
```

And in your controller functions you can use `selectedAllowedItem` and `selectedDenyItem` to move your selection between lists.

Comment: But the requirement is to have listbox and not dropdown (select)

Comment: @MrudangVora If you want to be able to select multiple item, you can add `multiple` attribute to `select` tag. In this way, you model will be an array of selected items.